# What's the outcome of setting node-integration to false when creating a new browser window in Electron?

Tags: electron

In order to get jQuery to load and function correctly in a HTML page I was opening in Electron (formerly Atom Shell), I had to disable Node integration when creating the `BrowserWindow` in my `main.js` file.

Can someone please tell me what setting `node-integration: false` will keep me from being able to do that I would normally be able to do had I not disabled it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting node-integration to false will disable node.js in the renderer process - i.e. your app can *only* do what a web browser will do. Instead of doing this, use Zepto.js which is compatible with Electron and has the same API.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot use Zepto.js at the point in time because Twitter Bootstrap isn't fully compatible with it (at least not until v4). I take your answer to mean doing things like `var ipc = require('ipc')` in the web page will no longer work with `node-integration: false`, correct?

Comment: Correct, everything involving `require` is out the door. jQuery is probably easy enough to patch to get working, I would do that. This is a common occurrence with Electron, JS developers are used to "Either DOM _or_ require", and Electron is a DOM environment *with* require, and many libraries Get Confused. It's usually a 1-2 line fix though.

Comment: Being new to node AND Electron, I am unsure what "node.js in the renderer process" means and I haven't found anything explaining it on the Electron documentation. Do you mean that the Electron modules available, like the module `electron` would not be available? How would one, in that case, talk to the main process?

Comment: If you load any dynamic content or render anything user provided this is really bad advice. In those cases you should definitely have the node-integration disabled, otherwise XSS vulnerability will let the attacker to do almost anything on your computer..

Comment: @EricMajerus it means that you can for example import `fs.readFileSync` and actually read the contents of the file on your local drive, from the renderer process. How cool is that?

But I wonder about performance implications too, are there any @PaulBetts?

Comment: There are no performance implications, why would you think there would be?