# Can not find module 'jquery-slider' in node.js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, electron

I have installed packages inside node-modules and I have required three package:

```
var lodash=require('lodash');
var jquery=require('jquery');
var slider=require('jquery-slider');
```

First two is working but slider is not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: You're going to have to figure out why not. Maybe that directory is empty.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: module.js:327
 throw err;
 ^

Comment: #tadman i have installed packages on node-modules folder , they are exist  properly in directory  [i.e: npm install jquery-slider]

Comment: Did you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265449/uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-jquery

Comment: yes I did, here in my case jquery is working but when I want to require jquery-slider its throwing above error