# Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' on require.resolve('jquery') webpack

Tags: jquery, node.js, webpack, jquery-lazyload

The problem is `Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'`

When i build it with script:

```
rm -rf dist && webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

Already tried with another clue like external etc but still got issue on jquery

Here is my package.json,

```
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.4.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "img-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.17.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js,

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './public/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            implementation: require("sass")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            {
                // Exposes jQuery for use outside Webpack build
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                use: [{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: 'jQuery'
                }, {
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: '$'
                }]
            }
        ]
    }, externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "bundle.css"
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './public/img', to: 'img' }
        ]),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
    ]
};
```

On my entry file:

```
import './css/reset.css';
import './css/main-1.0.css';
import './css/homepage-1.0.css';

import './js/jquery.lazy.min.js';
import './js/jquery.ellipsis.js';
import './js/main-1.0.js';
import './js/helper.js';
import './js/homepage-1.0.js';
```

I got stuck for this issue already 2 days..
any suggestion i'll do it,

the error i got is on terminal side[image]

best regards.

Comment: Have a sus at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32266859/11700321

Comment: nope. it's different issue, i got issue on building the webpack config

Comment: Try: "you need to install expose-loader in order to it to work properly npm install expose-loader --save-dev" as per a comment on this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46937798/11700321

Comment: Its already try using expose loeader but no hope u can see it i already use it. maybe another one?

Comment: aw... i'm doing something stupid.. yes u right bro @EGC4 on your first comment lol. wrong package.json that i look into is different folder.. haiyah ty2

Comment: Hahah, yw, glad its sorted

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using `require("jQuery")` in Windows, but it was not working in a Linux machine. Linux is case-sensitive, so I had to use `require("jquery")`.

Answer (score 0):

install 
npm i jquery
in same project solve my problem